# Use latin characters in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, string, latin1

How can store latin characters in appengine? (e.g. "peña") when I want to store this I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can change the Ñ by N, but, there not another and better way?

And if i encode the value, how can print "Peña" again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE stores strings in unicode. Perhaps encode your string in unicode before saving it.

```
value = "peña"

value.encode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error ("*Unicode* Decode Error"), it seems you could have more luck using Unicode - I'd try UTF-8.